# Declare a function in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm a newbie, I start programming at school and our professors asks us to realize a quicksort algorithm in assembly.

It is verry hard for me, could you give me a little help please.
I do not even know how to declare a function with a pointer ...

---

For exemple the prototype of the function in C++ is :
**void Quicksort(int* t, int size)**

---

In my opinion, I have to start like this but I'm not sure at all :

```
.text quicksort // it indicates that the variable belong to the quicksort function?

.size quicksort // same thing

:quicksort // it indicates that we declare a function named quicksort?
```

Assembly is verry hard ... I already did C / C++ programming in the past and it was easier to learn, if you can help me a little bit please, thanks ...

Comment: That depends on the assembler. Please tag your question with assembler (NASM, GAS, FASM, MASM or ...) and operating system. Normally you don't need to **declare** a function if it's not external.

Comment: I think this is based on RISC.


Somes instructions : lb (load byte), beq (branch if equal), add, addi, addiu, ...


I don't even know is all these expressions are available in all assembler types

Comment: Sorry, we can't answer this question if aren't able to identify the assembler (the program) you're using. The CPU architecture is less important.

Comment: I think it is MIPS, is that an assembler type?

Comment: We need to know the name of the computer program, the assembler, you're supposed to use to assemble the assembly code you're supposed to write. If you can't answer this question you'll need to go your professors for help. We can't help you here.

Comment: MIPS is name of the architecture for CPU, not assembler.

Comment: More important I think than identifying the assembler: what ABI should we obey for functions here?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few basics that need to be realized.

1. The pointer in the C++ function is for an int array. In MIPS, you [define arrays by their addresses in memory.](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~xujie/cs447/AccessingArray.htm)
2. [Functions are defined by setting up subroutine calls and using `jal`.](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~xujie/cs447/Mips/sub.html)
3. You should understand the quicksort algorithm already.

If you cannot even get a hello world program running, then there is no use asking on here right now. You will have to learn the basics of assembly first.